# Progress bar doesn't show on Windows server 2012

Tags: install4j

Install4j 5.1.5 doesn't show progress bar correctly on windows server 2012.

Please see attached pic. Similarly progress bar doesn't show up during installation also. Picture is taken of hello world app sample (64 bit). Download win server 2012 from here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh670538.aspx

Stack over flow is not permitting me to attach a picture. Kindly let me know your email address, will email to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a problem between the specific JRE and the Windows installation and not specifically something that install4j could work around with the native look and feel.

You can pass the VM argument

```
-Dinstall4j.nolaf=true
```

to the installer to avoid using the native look and feel.

---

Update 2013-08-23

A workaround for this problem will be included in the next release of install4j (5.1.7)

Comment: Hi Ingo, it works like a charm. It is still a work around as system had Sun's Jdk 1.7.0_17 (64 bit) and we didn't customize anything.               Wondering if we can "burn in" this argument into installer based on different OS. E.g. for Win server 2012, it should be enabled, but not for other window versions.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply !

Comment: Unfotunately, it's not possible to run code early enough in install4j to decide this programatically. You can set fixed VM parameters in the "VM arguments" property of the installer. One solution would be to set the cross platform look and feel conditionally in a "Run script" action via `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());`.

Comment: This is definitely a bug with Java on Windows Server 2012. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494812/java-look-and-feel-windows-server-2012-shows-progress-bar-too-thin)  <br/> Cross platform look and feel looks inferior in general. Especially file/dir chooser dialog. As this issue is only with progress bar, we have decided to live with it. Hopefully future versions of Java will fix the bug.

Comment: Please note that my advice two comments up does not work, the look and feel would be set to late in the initialization and most of the UI would be constructed with the native look and feel.

Answer (score -1):

Does adding jre 1.8 in the bundled jre do any help?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10316534)

Comment: i am unable to add my content in comment section. I too have the same problem as in question, and do not want to create another question. could you please suggest.

Comment: You can’t really do anything beside waiting to have enough reputation. See [here for more information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/185171).